# Syntax error in a Python library, and I'm not sure how to proceed

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm using pyramid 1.5.1 and python 3.2, and I just added quite a bit of code and a couple libraries to my project.

On running development.ini, I'm getting the error below.

If I had to take a wild guess, I would say that this particular library (looks like Markupsafe?) isn't compatible with Python3...but the project page seems to indicate that it is. Problem is, I'm not calling this library directly, it's being used by another library that would be very difficult to replace.

I'm new to Python programming, and I was wondering what my options are here  Or what the best way to debug is?

```
(finance-env)user1@finance1:/var/www/finance/corefinance/corefinance$ /var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/pserve /var/www/finance/corefinance/development.ini --reload
Starting subprocess with file monitor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/bin/pserve", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 51, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 316, in run
    global_conf=vars)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 340, in loadapp
    return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 55, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/var/www/finance/corefinance/corefinance/__init__.py", line 35, in main
    session_factory=session_factory
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 301, in __init__
    exceptionresponse_view=exceptionresponse_view,
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 412, in setup_registry
    self.include(inc)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 755, in include
    c(configurator)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar-2.1-py3.2.egg/pyramid_debugtoolbar/__init__.py", line 113, in includeme
    config.include('pyramid_mako')
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 727, in include
    c = self.maybe_dotted(callable)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 825, in maybe_dotted
    return self.name_resolver.maybe_resolve(dotted)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 320, in maybe_resolve
    return self._resolve(dotted, package)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 327, in _resolve
    return self._zope_dottedname_style(dotted, package)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid/path.py", line 370, in _zope_dottedname_style
    found = __import__(used)
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyramid_mako-1.0.2-py3.2.egg/pyramid_mako/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py3.2.egg/mako/lookup.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mako.template import Template
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py3.2.egg/mako/template.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mako.lexer import Lexer
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py3.2.egg/mako/lexer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from mako import parsetree, exceptions, compat
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py3.2.egg/mako/parsetree.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mako import exceptions, ast, util, filters, compat
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/Mako-1.0.0-py3.2.egg/mako/filters.py", line 38, in <module>
    import markupsafe
  File "/var/www/finance/finance-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/MarkupSafe-0.23-py3.2-linux-x86_64.egg/markupsafe/__init__.py", line 70
    def __new__(cls, base=u'', encoding=None, errors='strict'):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MarkupSafe` package uses syntax only supported by Python 3.3 and up. Python 3.2 is not supported anymore as of [version 0.16](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/markupsafe/blob/master/CHANGES#L14-L18).

The `u'unicode'` literal syntax was introduced in [PEP 414](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-414-explicit-unicode-literals) to make it easier to create library code that can support both Python 2 and 3.

Either upgrade to Python 3.3 (or 3.4 even), or downgrade `MarkupSafe` to 0.15, the last version to support Python 3.2.

I do see that [Mako *removes* the `MarkupSafe` dependency](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/mako/commits/4acc7ecaafdc1c36602d3ed7c02892c04210de13) when you are using Python 3.2; if nothing else depends on it is perhaps safe to remove the package altogether. The [`mako.filter` source code](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/mako/src/285bc818a50ccc0f9549630f7c4f4c250585c3e7/mako/filters.py?at=master#cl-37) certainly will fall back to a local implementation if the package is not installed.

Comment: It appears the dependency should have been removed, but if I uninstall mako and markupsafe and then run the initialize_db script,  it puts it right back in there.   I finally fixed it by just uninstalling markupsafe  and  then forcing version .15,  but now I feel dirty because my package isn't portable without some special instructions.

Comment: Then perhaps something else in your project depends on MarkupSafe *as well*? You can always add a pin to your `setup.py` based on the python version used to install.