# ocdev won't run: SyntaxError: invalid Syntax

Tags: python, owncloud

I can't get the ocdev tool to run. when I try running it i receive "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with some code. 
My guess is maybe wrong python version? Since python --version outputs 2.7.3.
I also have python3 installed but it's not the standard version. I installed ocdev using pip-3.2. I already tried reinstalling it multiple times. I also have python3-jinja2 installed. I'm running debian 7.8.

Here is the whole error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ocdev", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ocdev==0.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'ocdev')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/ocdev/application.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ocdev.plugins import PLUGINS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/ocdev/plugins/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ocdev.plugins.startapp.startapp import StartApp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/ocdev/plugins/startapp/startapp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 639
    u'\xff\xff\xff\xff'.encode('iso-8859-15')
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get ocdev to work with Python 3.2 you need to install legacy versions of Jinja2([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252804/syntax-error-in-jinja-2-library)) and MarkupSafe([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391440/syntax-error-in-a-python-library-and-im-not-sure-how-to-proceed)). This is because the newer versions require Python 3.3.

To do the proper install follow the regular [setup guide](https://github.com/owncloud/ocdev/blob/master/README.rst#installation) and use the following pip/pip3 commands:

```
pip install -Iv Jinja2==2.6
pip install -Iv MarkupSafe==0.15
pip install ocdev
```

I also reported this in the ocdev GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/owncloud/ocdev/issues/37).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running Python 3.2.

To use the `u'unicode'` syntax with Python 3 you'll need at least Python 3.3. (see [What's New In Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/whatsnew/3.3.html))

Comment: If the answer was helpful you can mark my answer as accepted. It will give me more reputation score and the motivation to answer other questions.